# Setting namepsace for envelope and using this namespace in tag

Tags: c#, xml, soap

The SOAP Service requests me to send such a format of XML envelope:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://myNamespace.com">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <typ:pushData>
            ...
```

But my client sends something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <pushData xmlns="http://myNamespace.com">
            ...
```

My clients steps for sending looks like this:

```
pushDataResp = ServiceProxyProvider<IServiceBinding>.Invoke(Program.ServiceEndpoint, x => x.pushData(xxx, yyy));

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://myNamespace.com")]
public interface IServiceBinding
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceException), Action = "", Name = "ServiceException")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
    int pushData(Xxx xxx, Yyy yyy);
}
```

How can I achieve requested format in my C# code?

Comment: Is this actually causing you a problem? Because the two are semantically equivalent. Anything vaguely compliant at the other end shouldn't see any difference.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But first one is accepted, but second one isn't.